# Is it possible to narrow object value types when accessing object with varied value types using a dynamic key?

Tags: typescript

Minimal test case follows ([TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gPICMBWECYyA3gFDJXJwBcyWUoA5pdbvSAK4C2u05AL7lyYAJ4AHFOiwBpCGNSSUAXmQBrBQHsYaTDgJEwIhFpBZkPMXnzFka0nWQAiBHDDOANMg4BmACyCNBh6WDZGANzkpuYkmmL2yADkcEnBoWDyispR5MC6ABTiUjqW1gTEANrxALrIAIQqakmMLEkAlGRsVGAAFlBaAO5oygCiUANQBe1RwuRWNlW1iUkAJlrMSRFAA))

```typescript
interface TestObject {
    a: string
    b: number
}

type TestKeyType = keyof TestObject

const myObjct = {a: "cat", b:34} as TestObject;
const key = 'a' as TestKeyType;

if (typeof myObjct[key] !== 'string') {
    throw TypeError();
}

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
myObjct[key] = 'dog';
```

Essentially, I have a configuration object where the values can be various types. When I update this object, the key depends on user input but based on the category of input I can know if it's a boolean or number or string etc.

As shown, I can write a type guard which should guarantee what type the dynamic key corresonds to but Typescript disagrees.

Is there something else concise I can do to prove to Typescript that my type is valid?

I know I can enumerate the keys that correspond to each value type to check but it seems a bit verbose and redundant; I'd prefer to minimize the places I need to update when expanding the keys in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a user-defined type guard for this: `typeCheck(obj, key, type)` will tell you whether `obj[key]` has the type `type`. The wrinkle is that `type` has to be passed as a string that `typeof` can return at runtime, so you need a mapping from those strings to Typescript types; this mapping is named `Primitive` below. Add whatever else you need to this mapping (e.g. `bigint`) as necessary.

```
type Primitive = {
    number: number,
    string: string,
    boolean: boolean,
}
type KeyAssignableTo<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T]

function typeCheck<T, P extends keyof Primitive>(obj: T, key: keyof T, type: P): key is KeyAssignableTo<T, Primitive[P]> {
    return typeof obj[key] === type;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(!typeCheck(myObject, key, 'string')) {
    throw TypeError();
}

// key: 'a'
myObject[key] = 'dog';
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gPICMBWECYyA3gFDJXJwBcyWUoA5pdbvSAK4C2u05AL7kwATwAOKdFgDSEUagkoAvMgDW8gPYw0mHASJhyIpcgAKTHsDDAAbirJsq3PtE69+UADROGYJiDM9IwsPtTIuJqaADYQcCD0kTFxID7CYpLIcqIAghgYwMwgcLixqJoAPKheyABqAHzIqqQA2jLIoOpaOqgAuvSobb3IEAAekCAAJhh1yAD8WcicEPZQgi0aotpovcYwXCDEwJogyBkQAMIAFkRqVTVmI+MQUzOb2xbAVjb29QAUmgIAxqm3o7x6NXO9DMAEowfIOjNsnkCkUSmVKtVzJZrHYIC0zL1GhRwlAIGAuFBTudtoD8Bt5MNlMyzkoANxCPYHI4nM56P48UR4QjEAZ6YWGEHyMWyeSKSRw5C2TTASaOcLAGB-ACE52utwFQoMxClohqAHIQoFzTCYerwtQwFcoJoAO5oJQAUSgLqgfxhHPCwl8AHoQ11RPRzXBzb5BRLiAzREzkObJppmOaOcIgA)

Comment: I believe your answer is much better than my, so I decided to remove mine.
Also, you can use `assert` function to make code more generic and `typescriptish` )

Comment: This works great; it seems so generic that I wonder if I should just have a module for exporting common useful type guards I use in my project...